# Set substring start and end at clostest other substring

Tags: php, string, substring

I'm a real php newbie. I hope that's not such a stupid question.
So I've a string:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor START sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore END magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt END ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem END ipsum dolor sit amet."
```

Inside that string there's my "START". I get that startposition by

```
$startpos = strpos($string, "START");
```

Now, I want the position of the first following "END".
I need that position, because I want that substring between the "START" and the closest "END".

I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start = strpos($string, 'START')+5;
$end = strpos($string, 'END', $start);

$inside = trim(substr($string, $start, $end - $start));
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/VAYGApAg)

The `+5` accounts for the letters of 'START', starting the new `$inside` string *after* 'START'.

`$inside` is built using [**substr()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - `substr(string, start pos, length)`

[**trim()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes extra whitespace from the ends of `$inside`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use again [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) but adding offset of your first search :

```
$startpos = strpos($string, "START");
$endpos = strpos($string, "END", $startpos);
```